# Can you use String.trim() on browsers safely or should I add a shim?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it safe to use [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim#Browser_compatibility) and if not is it ok to add it automatically if it doesn't exist?

It shows currently only 50% availability on [*Can I use*](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_string_trim).

[image]

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim#Browser_compatibility) shows full? support.
[image]

Comment: MDN doesn't show _"full support"_. Any browser older than the versions shown will not support it. This is the same as what you see on _Can I use_ which even states that it gets its data from MDN

Comment: I'm not sure where they're getting 50% from, but IE 9+ is something I'd personally feel pretty darn safe using without bothering with a polyfill. That was almost a decade ago.

Comment: The pages you linked to show the browser support stats. What do you want from us that you haven't already read?

Comment: _"I'm not sure where they're getting 50% from"_  it's a percentage calculated based on [these stats](https://caniuse.com/usage-table)

Comment: I've added images showing what I see. The 50% is in the upper right hand corner `Global 50%`. The `Full support` is in the green box in the lower left hand corner.

Comment: It's saying that 50% of [globally tracked user browser stats](https://caniuse.com/usage-table) will support the feature. I'm really not sure what you're asking at this stage

Comment: The CanIUse page is really confusing there. `trim` has existed since IE 9... if you still need to polyfill it... I'm sorry.

Comment: _"Full support"_ on MDN means that there are no caveats. For comparison, see something like [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility) which has a mix of full, partial and no support in various browser versions

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of the modern browsers support `.trim()`.
You need to look at your users data (their browsers) and compare that with [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_string_trim).